# Unable to catch elements of a global list (Polygon inheritance)

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I am trying to catch elements of the **sides** list I declared on the top of the Polygon class but I am having problem in the **sideLenght** method that is besically a list of lists (I dont understand why). I am therefore unable to create calculate the perimeter of my triangle. Here is what how I start :

```
t=Triangle()
t.sideLength()
t.findPeri()
```

everything works well until I am calling the findPeri() method. Here is what I get in return:

```
t.findPeri()
```

what i get is the below:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

What's really going on here? and How can I sort this out? My whole code is below:

```
class Polygon:
   sides= []
   def __init__(self, num_of_sides):
       self.n= num_of_sides
       self.num_of_sides= int(input('Enter the number of sides: '))



   def sideLength(self):
       """This method appends all sides of the polygon into a list"""
       for i in range(self.n):
           side = int(input('Enter the length the side: ' + str(i+1) + ' : '))
           Polygon.sides.append(self.side)
       print Polygon.side


class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self):
       Polygon.__init__(self,3)

    def findPeri(self):
       print  'The toatal area of your perimeter is: ',sum(Polygon.sides)
```

Comment: The only modification of Polygon.sides is commented out...

Comment: thanks. @MaximeChéramy .. I change that now // bit the situation  is the same

Comment: Apart from being commented out as mentioned above, the `Polygon.sides.append(self.side)` will try to add something that doesn't exist, either change `self.side` to `side` or `side` to `self.side`

Comment: @KacperFloriański  thanks. it was the side variable I decalred. thanks that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the self keyword like this for the sides property. That should fix your issues.

```
class Polygon:

   def __init__(self, num_of_sides):
       self.n= num_of_sides
       self.num_of_sides= int(input('Enter the number of sides: '))
       self.sides = []


   def sideLength(self):
       """This method appends all sides of the polygon into a list"""
       for i in range(self.n):
           side = int(input('Enter the length the side: ' + str(i+1) + ' : '))
           self.sides.append(side)
       print self.sides


class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self):
       Polygon.__init__(self,3)

    def findPeri(self):
       print  'The total area of your perimeter is: ',sum(self.sides)
```

Comment: thanks. I also had help from a comment below. I understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use sum(self.sides) instead of sum(Polygon.sides)

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, `self.side` is never defined (`side` is, but those aren't the same).  I suspect you're appending some list to `Polygon.sides`, instead of `side`. There are some other problems here.  Each instance of `Polygon` should have its own list of sides.  Also, as a rule, you should try to keep code asking for user input out of things like `__init__`, and pass those values in as arguments.  Here's how I would set things up:

```
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides
        self.perimeter = sum(sides)

class Triangle(Polygon):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super(Triangle, self).__init__([a, b, c])
    @classmethod
    def input(cls):
        a = int(input("Enter side 1: "))
        b = int(input("Enter side 2: "))
        c = int(input("Enter side 3: "))
        return cls(a, b, c)
```